# Facebook Comment Plugin is not working with smarty template

Tags: facebook, templates, plugins, smarty, comments

The facebook comment plug in is not working with smarty template. The code I am using is given below

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> {literal}<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=APP_ID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>{/literal} <fb:comments width="425"></fb:comments>
```

Please check this and let me know if there is any solution for this

Thanks In Advance
Rose

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely because of the order in which this template loads on the page. You are most likely going to need to manually initialize the XFBML on your page for the tag to render. This is probably beyond what a template engine is going to be able to do. You are going to need to call FB.init(xfbml:true); after the template has loaded on the page. Also, change the script reference to

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

The initilization call should occur only after the above script is loaded.

```
<script>
FB.init({xfbml:true});
</script?
```

Comment: Yeah, you probably aren't going to get it working without modifying the source of what you are working on directly. Templates and javascript do not mix very well.